# How to explicitly set type of constant value in SELECT clause

Tags: firebird

I want to use a double constant value inside Select clause. If I do following in a query window, it gets executed successfully.

```
SELECT (1171.80) as IN_STOCK,
        . . . other columns
```

But when I try running same query inside a report and passing the Constant in a parameter like shown below,

```
SELECT ($P{IN_STOCK}) as IN_STOCK,
       . . . other columns
```

It throws the following error.

```
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -804
Data type unknown
```

Apparently DB is failing to detect the Data type of the constant. How can i define type inside query or add a cast to double.

I tried adding cast like `Select cast($P{IN_STOCK} as double) as IN_STOCK` but this won't do the trick.

Comment: What's wrong with `cast(... as double)`?

Comment: It gives `Dynamic SQL Error, SQL error code = -104, Token unknown - line 2, column 32 )`  that is the closing bracket of cast

Comment: The type name is `double precision`, `double` is an incomplete sequence and thus yields a token unknown error. However, a literal of `1171.80` is `NUMERIC(18,2)` (or `DECIMAL(18,2)`). Casting parameters in the select list requires Firebird 2.5 or higher, IIRC.

Comment: I tried `(cast($P{IN_STOCK} as double precision)) as IN_STOCK` now it give TypeConversionException i.e. `Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.field.TypeConvertionException: SQL type for this field is not yet supported.`  The passed parameter is of type `java.lang.Double`. My DB ODS Version is 11.2

Comment: @AlphaTry Jaybird supports double precision just fine, so I'm not sure what would be going on there, I however do notice that you seem to be using an old version of Jaybird. Please post a **new** question and tag it with firebird and jaybird (and other relevant tags), and provide a [mcve] (preferably in plain JDBC), and make sure to include the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel FB 2.1.7 IBExpert 2019 - `select cast( :x as smallint ) from rdb$database` - like a charm :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The Ok, then it was 2.1 :)

Comment: @Arioch'The It shouldn't, but if the OP is using Jaybird 2.2 or earlier, and the field is identified as SQL_D_FLOAT instead of SQL_DOUBLE then that may be the case, but as far as I'm aware SQL_D_FLOAT should never actually surface in the protocol.